# Spacemacs: How do I disable smartparens globally and automatically?

Tags: spacemacs

I want to disable smartparens in spacemacs from turning on *ever*. I know I can toggle them off globally using SPC t C-p. I don't want to have to type that every time I open spacemacs.

I've tried throwing (while not really understanding what I'm doing) the following into my .spacemacs user-config() section to no avail:

```
(setq-default turn-off-smartparens-mode t)
```

That didn't do anything, so I tried:

```
(add-hook 'disable-smartparens
          (lambda()
            (smartparens-strict-mode -1)
            (turn-off-smartparens-mode t)))
```

Which also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add it to `dotspacemacs-excluded-packages`:

```
dotspacemacs-excluded-packages
'(
  smartparens
 )
```